# Scrollable area within Primefaces panel

Tags: css, primefaces, scroll, jsf-2.2, scrollpane

I use a Primefaces fullpage Layout, and i want to insert in the center unit a panel (`p:panel`) with a scrollable content (and fixed header), but it didn't work. I have tried :

- making the content of the panel scrollable
- inserting the content in a `p:scrollPanel`
- inserting the content in a scrollable `p:outputPanel`

None of these solutions worked. I think that the major problem is that I can't set a fixed height/width because the content of the center unit must take all the "remaining size". Someone can give me an hint?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:xyrion="http://www.rohag.ch/xyrion/jsf"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="test.css"/>

</h:head>
<h:body>


    <p:layout fullPage="true">

        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header="Top" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
            <h:outputText value="North unit content."/>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" header="Bottom" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
            <h:outputText value="South unit content."/>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header="Left" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">

        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" header="Right" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true"
                      effect="drop">
            <h:outputText value="Right unit content."/>
        </p:layoutUnit>


        <p:layoutUnit position="center">

            <p:panel header="Title" toggleable="false" closable="false">

                <p:outputPanel style="display:block; width:calc(100% - 20px); height:calc(100% - 20px); overflow: auto">

                    <table style="width:1000px">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Firstname</th>
                            <th>Lastname</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td>
                            <td>50</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td>
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:panel>


        </p:layoutUnit>

    </p:layout>


</h:body>
</html>
```

layout.css

```
 .ui-layout-center .ui-layout-unit-content {
                      overflow:hidden !important;
                  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally don't like the "ui-layout" templating. The template can be made better and with bigger control using just custom CSS, maybe the [Grid CSS](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml) and XHTML.

For your problem I would do this:

1. Set the `panel` component height to 100% (you can see that `ui-layout-unit-content` have a calculated height and the panel height will be relative to that):

   `#your-panel-id.ui-panel { height: 100% }`
2. Set the `panel` content height to 100%:

   `#your-panel-id .ui-panel-content { height: 100% }`
3. Set your `outputPanel` height and overflow:

   `#your-outputPanel-id { 
        height: calc(100% - someSpecificHeight); 
        overflow: auto;
   }`

Note: "someSpecificHeight" - is relative to your application CSS. I tested on mine (I use Modena template) and  it was bigger than `50px` in order to have all the table elements visible on scroll.

Hope it works for you! :)

Comment: I'm impressed, it works, thx very much! I will take a look also to Grid CSS